# Como efetuar PULL mantendo as alterações do HEAD?

Tags: git

Foram efetuadas algumas alterações, commitadas e houve conflito em alguns arquivos. Caso não houvesse `commits` efetuados, resolveria da seguinte forma:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Porém com `commits` efetuados, como pode ser feito um `git pull` mantendo as alterações do `head` nesses conflitos?

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito sua dúvida, mas se ao dar *pull*, houve conflitos, você resolvendo esses conflitos, você continua com o código das alterações, ou seja, pelo que entendi você só precisa resolver os conflitos e continuar seu trabalho.

Comment: Sim, só precisa resolver os conflitos. Mas quero uma maneira automatizada, já que nesse caso todos os conflitos serão mantidos pela versão local e descartado o `origin`.

Comment: O git consegue fazer um *merge* entre os novos *commits* que você obteve dando *pull* e o seu código que foi commitado localmente, mas resolver **conflitos** automaticamente ele não resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> quero uma maneira automatizada, já que nesse caso todos os conflitos serão mantidos pela versão local e descartado o origin

Use

```
$ git pull -s ours
```

Isso vai resolver os conflitos sempre dando prioridade à versão local.

[**Git Merge Strategies**](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies)