# Como resolver conflito de merge automaticamente, sem precisar editar os arquivos manualmente?

Tags: git, merge

Primeiro vou mostrar o cenário atual, e em seguida a tentativa de merge e explicação do problema:

## Montagem do cenário

Tenho um arquivo (`arq.txt`) contendo uma linha (`abc`), devidamente *commitado*.

Fiz uma alteração adicionando outra linha, e agora o arquivo ficou assim:

```
abc
def
```

Fiz o commit, e o repositório ficou assim:

```bash
$ git log --format=oneline --decorate
8b0d355e7187765df9e9bb4b91a8d87966c3783d (HEAD -> master) segundo commit
f1b3dcbae69f2fdf95487f0a8bf76a5c16c8690d primeiro commit
```

Ou seja, no primeiro commit, o arquivo só tinha `abc`, e no segundo commit eu adicionei a linha `def`:

```bash
$ git diff f1b3dcb 8b0d355
diff --git a/arq.txt b/arq.txt
index f2ba8f8..85137a6 100644
--- a/arq.txt
+++ b/arq.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-abc
\ No newline at end of file
+abc
+def
\ No newline at end of file
```

Depois criei um branch, a partir do primeiro commit:

```bash
$ git branch feature f1b3dcb
$ git checkout feature # ou git switch feature, para Git >= 2.23.0
```

Assim, o conteúdo do arquivo passou a ser novamente `abc`. Então adicionei outra linha:

```
abc
feature
```

Fiz o commit e agora temos:

```bash
$ git log --format=oneline --decorate
1db4fecea229b9d63f52a22e86e2a38c438fc9f1 (HEAD -> feature) adicionar feature
f1b3dcbae69f2fdf95487f0a8bf76a5c16c8690d primeiro commit
```

## Tentativa de merge

Em seguida, voltei para o branch master e tentei fazer o merge com o branch feature, mas deu conflito (pois ambos alteram a mesma linha do arquivo):

```bash
$ git checkout master
$ git merge feature
Auto-merging arq.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in arq.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Como resultado, o arquivo `arq.txt` ficou assim:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
abc
def
||||||| f1b3dcb
abc
=======
abc
feature
>>>>>>> feature
```

**Eu sei** que posso resolver [assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282273/112052) e [assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/390777/112052) (ou seja, editando o arquivo e fazendo o commit em seguida).

Mas a pergunta é: **tem como resolver o conflito automaticamente, sem precisar editar o arquivo manualmente?**

Comment: E mais uma vez, antes que alguém estranhe que eu mesmo respondi minha própria pergunta, isso é [**perfeitamente aceitável e dentro das regras**](/help/self-answer). Inclusive, a [página de fazer pergunta](/questions/ask) tem uma [opção para postar a própria resposta junto com a pergunta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPEQw.png). Claro que se alguém tiver outra solução, com certeza deve postá-la. O objetivo é trazer este conhecimento para o site (pois fiz uma busca e até encontrei coisas relacionadas, mas nada explicando em detalhes as opções da resposta abaixo).

Comment: já que respondeu, poderia marcar como aceita :-), ou espera alguma mais completa?

Comment: @Danizavtz O sistema só deixa  aceitar minha própria resposta depois de dois dias. Independente disso, se alguém tiver outra solução, pode postar sem problemas

Comment: @Danizavtz E só pra deixar claro, se outra resposta for melhor, mais completa, etc, a aceitarei sem problemas (afinal, esse é o critério para aceitação, independente de quem postou). Eu respondi com base no que conheço (é assim que eu resolveria o problema), mas como eu não sei tudo, claro que pode aparecer alguém com uma solução melhor (inclusive, gostaria muito que aparecesse). Afinal, essa é - pelo menos espera-se - a grande vantagem de sites como esse, aproveitar o conhecimento coletivo e aprender com ele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode alterar as opções de estratégia do merge. A [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies) explica todas as possibilidades, mas neste caso poderíamos escolher se vou ficar com a versão que está no master (segunda linha contém `def`) ou no branch feature (segunda linha contém `feature`), usando a opção `--strategy-option` (ou o equivalente `-X`).

Por exemplo, se eu escolher ficar com a versão que está no master (segunda linha do arquivo será `def`, ignorando a alteração feita no branch feature), basta fazer:

```bash
git merge feature --strategy-option=ours

# ou
git merge feature -X ours
```

Mas se eu quiser a versão que está no branch feature (segunda linha do arquivo será `feature`, ignorando a linha `def` do branch master):

```bash
git merge feature --strategy-option=theirs

# ou
git merge feature -X theirs
```

Basicamente, como estou no branch master fazendo merge com o feature, então "ours" indica a versão do master, enquanto "theirs" indica a versão do branch que estou *mergeando* (no caso, o branch feature).

Com isso, não aparece mais a mensagem de conflito e o merge é concluído sem erros.

---

Se eu quiser que o arquivo contenha ambas as alterações (tanto a linha contendo `def` quanto a linha contendo `feature`), aí não tem jeito, tenho que tentar fazer o merge para causar o conflito e depois editar o arquivo manualmente. E na minha opinião faz sentido, pois se dois branches diferentes alteraram o mesmo arquivo no mesmo lugar, talvez não seja uma boa ideia juntar ambas as alterações automaticamente.

Pode até ter situações em que faça sentido, mas por experiência própria eu diria que na grande maioria dos casos é melhor revisar manualmente esses trechos. Afinal, se for para juntar, qual linha deveria vir antes? Ou ambas seriam juntadas em uma linha só? Em qual ordem? Etc. Vale lembrar que isso é diferente de ter alterações em pontos diferentes do arquivo, pois ao se fazer o merge nesses casos, seria "óbvio" que ambas devem estar no resultado final (e nestes casos nem teria conflito). Mas estamos falando do caso em que houve duas alterações distintas na(s) mesma(s) linha(s).

O Git (ao menos na versão atual) não fornece uma maneira de fazer isso automaticamente, e o jeito é você mesmo resolver o conflito (olhando e editando o arquivo) antes de proceder com o merge.

---

Evidentemente, isso é para os casos mais simples, como o citado na pergunta. Para situações mais complicadas, a documentação cita as várias outras alternativas (por exemplo, se um branch só adicionou espaços no final de uma linha, há opções para ignorar; se deve considerar ou ignorar arquivos renomeados; etc). Mas quanto a **resolver conflitos automaticamente, sem precisar editar o arquivo**, as soluções ficam restritas às opções `ours` e `theirs`.

---

**Atenção**: não confundir a opção `ours` com a estratégia `ours`.

Na solução acima, eu usei a **opção** (tanto que na linha de comando eu uso `--strategy-option=ours`). Mas existe também a **estratégia** (`--strategy=ours`). A diferença é que a estratégia nem sequer olha para o que o outro branch fez.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que, além de ter modificado o arquivo `arq.txt`, o branch feature também adicionou outro arquivo (`other.txt`).

Se fizermos o merge com a **opção** `ours` (`git merge feature --strategy-option=ours`), a resolução do conflito usará a versão do arquivo `arq.txt` que está no master (ou seja, a segunda linha é `def`), e o arquivo `other.txt` será adicionado ao master (afinal, não houve conflito para este arquivo, então usa-se o que estava no branch feature).

Mas se fizermos o merge com a **estratégia** `ours` (`git merge feature --strategy=ours`), o arquivo `arq.txt` também ficará como está no master (ou seja, a segunda linha é `def`), mas o arquivo `other.txt` **não** será adicionado ao master. Isso porque a estratégia `ours` ignora as alterações feitas no outro branch.

Já o `theirs` é somente uma opção, pois não existe uma estratégia com o mesmo nome (ou seja, só pode ser usado com `--strategy-option`).

---

Relacionado:

- [Como efetuar PULL mantendo as alterações do HEAD?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214645/112052)
- [Existe alguma forma forçar a sobrescrita do stash em cima das modificações atuais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/425409/112052)